# Azure Performance - Ping Test - Inconsistent values between Availability and Performance

Tags: performance, azure, azure-mobile-services, ping

In Azure you can create simple [ping test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-web-app-availability) of your app. It's call ping but it is Get request of a url.
By default, the url is your root url.

The thing is the responses times of thes results are in the range of 2 to 10ms. However, I can never reach these response times nor with Fiddler or Postman. My range is more 100 to 400ms. And I'm closer to the datacenter than the computers running the ping tests in Azure.

It is a bit as if the ping tests where not downloading the content page.
Does anyone know?

**UPDATE**
I have setup my ping test in the Availability section. The responses times I mention above appear in the Performance section. Back in the Availability section, average response time is 1,6 sec. These two sections show inconsistent values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER:

The Performance section lists how long it took from your server receiving the request to sending something back to the client, it doesn't count network latency at all.

---

I believe they only check the response status without downloading the content if you don't require a *content match*.

Below is an example of the configuration for my blog.

If you wish, you can make sure the test downloads the content by ticking the *Content match* checkbox, and specifying that the content must contain the text that is somewhere near the end of your index page (like in a footer).

[image: Example configuration for ping test]

Comment: That's fine not to download the content. But how can I reproduce it with Fiddler or Postman?

Comment: Well, in Fiddler you can look at the Statistics tab to see when you got the response headers. You can't see when you got the status code though, as that is the first thing the client gets. ServerBeginResponse might be pretty close.

Comment: The raw time it took for the bytes to be sent to the server and for you to receive the headers would be GotResponseHeaders - FiddlerBeginRequest.

Comment: @François Updated answer. That section only counts server processing time, while availability counts network latency as well.